# Trying to stop urls such as mydomain.com/index.php/garbage-after-slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know very little about `.htaccess` files and mod-rewrite rules.  Looking at my statcounter information today, I noticed that a visitor to my site entered a url as follows:

```
http://mywebsite.com/index.php/contact-us
```

Since there is no such folder or file on the website and no broken links on the site, I'm assuming this was a penetration attempt.  What was displayed to the visitor was the output of the index.php file, but without benefit of the associated CSS layout.

I need to create a rewrite rule that will either remove the information after `index.php` (or any .php file), or perhaps more appropriately, insert a question mark (after the .php filename), so that any following garbage will be treated like a parameter (and will be gracefully ignored if no parameters are required).

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: What do you have in your `.htaccess` file now?

Comment: I don't have an .htaccess file at the moment - didn't really know that until I started investigating this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only expecting real directories and real files that do exist, then you can add this to an `.htaccess` file. What it does is it takes a non-existent file or directory request and gives the user the index.php page with the original request as a query string. `[QSA]` appends any existing query string.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [PT,QSA]
```

Comment: If I want this to be more generalized, so that *ANY* .php file has the ? put after it, how do I need to modify the search condition?  Right now, it looks to be specific to index.php

Comment: @user1609659 We're only trying to catch people who are purposely adjusting your URLs to see how your site works.

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying, and thank you again for trying to help.  I created an .htaccess file containing the code you provided, and it had no effect (the trailing / and following garbage are still there, and the page renders without the CSS).  Perhaps I need to clean the cache on my browser, so I'll try that as well.

Comment: Is there a way on StackOverflow to say Thank You without crediting for a solution?  Your post probably resulted in the proper "similar questions" being shown on the right side of the screen, and those eventually led me to a solution.

Comment: @user1609659 If you've found your solution (or if for some reason this one didn't work) then you can post your own answer and mark it answered. If you found the exact answer in another question, then delete this question as it's a duplicate. Then upvote the answer the question you've chosen. An upvote indicates a potentially correct (or helpful) answer, as some questions can be answered in more than one method. If you mark an answer as THE answer then the person gets more points for the answer (but you can only do this as the original poster of the question).

Comment: None of the other answers I found were correct.  They only gave me something to think about.  It turns out my answer is not working either.  If someone adds another level of subfolder:  (e.g. mydomain.com/anyfile.php/first-garbage/second-garbage), my solution works for "first-garbage", but fails (with original symptoms) when it encounters "second-garbage".  So, I'm still searching.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, using information provided by AbsoluteZero as well as other threads that popped up on the right side of the screen as the solution came closer.

Here's the code that worked for me...

```
Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off

# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]

# translate PATH_INFO information into a parameter
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php(\/)(.*) $1.php?$3 [R=301,L]

# rewrite /dir/file?query to /dir/file.php?query
RewriteRule ^([\w\/-]+)(\?.*)?$ $1.php$2 [L,T=application/x-httpd-php]
```

I got the removal of trailing slash from another post on StackOverflow.  However, even after removing the trailing slash, the rewrite rule did not account for someone appending what looks to be valid information after the .php file

(For example:  mysite.com/index.php/somethingelse)

My goal was to either remove the "/somethingelse", or render it harmless.  The PATH_INFO rule locates a "/" after the .php file, and turns everything else from that point forward into a query string (which will usually be ignored by the PHP file).